# Select Random Rows in MySQL for JOIN with another table

Tags: mysql, join, random

I am migrating millions of rows from table1 to table2. After the migration, I am trying to spot check certain rows to see if they are migrated properly. Here is a sample SQL query [not the exact one]:

```
SELECT     tbl1.name,
           tbl1.address,
           tbl2.name,
           tbl2.new_address
FROM       
          (SELECT * 
           FROM table1
           ORDER BY   RAND() limit 10) tbl1
INNER JOIN table2 tbl2
ON         tbl1.name = tbl2.name;
```

I am trying to select 10 rows from table 1 to join with table2 for checking. If I ran this query with an explain, it does a full table scan i.e., all rows in table 1 (which is > 130 million). How to optimize this query in MySQL?

Comment: Many good approaches here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast
Off hand, I'd favor the generating random offsets one, if that'd work for your data, less strenuous SQL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestions from http://bigdatums.net/2017/01/05/select-random-sample-records-mysql/

```
SELECT     tbl1.name,
           tbl1.address,
           tbl2.name,
           tbl2.new_address
FROM       
          (SELECT * 
           FROM table1
           WHERE RAND() < 0.2 LIMIT 10) tbl1
INNER JOIN table2 tbl2
ON         tbl1.name = tbl2.name;
```

seems to be sufficient for my case i.e., RAND() < 0.2 LIMIT 10.